# Download Video using Alamofire and then Play on AV player

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, avplayer, nsdata

I have Used Following Code to Download Video from the `URL`. It is working fine for Downloading it the Video.

```
func downloadVideo(){

    Alamofire.request("https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4").downloadProgress(closure:{ (progress) in
    print(progress.fractionCompleted)
    self.progressView.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)

    }).responseData{ (response) in
       print(response.result)
       print(response.result.value!)
       print(response.result.description)

        if let data = response.result.value {
            let obj = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: obj!)!)
            self.playerController.player = player
            self.addChildViewController(self.playerController)
            self.view.addSubview(self.playerController.view)
            self.playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
            player.play()

        }

    }
```

But I want to Play this Video in `AVPlayer`

I have Found that May be Video is Downloaded as `NSData`. am in Right.?
Can Anyone Help me How to Play this Video once it has Finished Downloading?

> It Would be good if anyone Can suggest some another Code For
>   downloading video with Progress Bar and then Playing it in Swift 3.0.

TIA.

Comment: `let obj = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8); let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: obj!)!)` That doesn't make sense. `obj` is supposed to be the content of the video (bytes), how can it be transformed into String? And HOW is this supposed to be an URL?

Comment: Do you really need to donwload it? Why not just doing `let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string:"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!)`? Else, you need to save the `data` into your app (FileManager or something like that) at some file path, and use that path for `AVPlayer(url: URL(string:myFilePath))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Afters Hours of Searching for this stuff

I came up With an easy and reliable way of Converting the NSData in URL so that it can be played by AVPlayer

```
func downloadVideo(){

    Alamofire.request("https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4").downloadProgress(closure : { (progress) in
    print(progress.fractionCompleted)
    self.progressView.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
    }).responseData{ (response) in
       print(response)
       print(response.result.value!)
       print(response.result.description)
        if let data = response.result.value {

            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let videoURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("video.mp4")
            do {
                try data.write(to: videoURL)
                } catch {
                print("Something went wrong!")
            }
            print(videoURL)
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
            self.playerController.player = player
            self.addChildViewController(self.playerController)
            self.view.addSubview(self.playerController.view)
            self.playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

**You Can Use this Following Piece of Code to convert that**

```
if let data = response.result.value {

            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let videoURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("video.mp4")
            do {
                try data.write(to: videoURL) // Pass this videoURL to AVPlayer after Downloading Video it will be played.
                } catch {
                print("Something went wrong!")
            }
            print(videoURL)
```

---

As per the Request, 
Here is the Source Code of the full implementation.

[Download Source Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1piEJnYhrpSp28wsmkWuIdiu7ZnXt2XP-/view?usp=sharing)

> **P.S:-** This was made thinking of a demo. Many of you will argue that this code can be optimised and can be done better, but yes this
>   is an demo and you can pick some of the part or whole depending upon
>   your Requirement